# + / - not visible in vote breakout for posts with many votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, vote-count

On [posts with many votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator/11155703#11155703), when viewing the vote breakout, the "**+**" and "**-**" symbols are not visible:

[image]

This is inconsistent with posts which have fewer votes, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766785/fixing-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-for-a-stuck-my/4797328#4797328), where they *are* visible:

[image]

This is inconsistent, and it surprised me the first time I saw it. Can this be fixed to correctly show the + / - for posts with many votes?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/vote-split-does-not-include-leading-sign-when-count-exceeds-99, which was marked [meta-tag:status-by-design] (and corresponding [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260444/no-plus-sign-when-viewing-vote-counts-that-are-3-digits-or-more) without answers)

Comment: This is fixed in the [Stack Overflow Unoficial Patch](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup)

Answer (score 25):

They're intentionally stripped so that the numbers fit in more cases. Not to worry; the top number is always the number of upvotes and the lower one is always the number of downvotes, and a hover-tip explains this for those who might be unfamiliar.

#### See also: [Vote split does not include leading sign when count exceeds 99](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/vote-split-does-not-include-leading-sign-when-count-exceeds-99)

Comment: Another related post [Large down-vote count doesn't display negative sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230536)

Comment: As if the color wouldn't be cue enough.

Comment: Or the position...

Comment: Color or position are fine for users w/out any visual impairments. But for those who are not so lucky, not so much. Granted that part of the voting widget is completely inaccessible at the moment anyway, and the up/down anchor tags are improperly used.

Comment: Why not take away the `-` and `+` to make it consistent?

Comment: Why is consistency so important here, @cybermonkey? The vast majority of posts will have the  signs.

Comment: @shog9 because saying something is inconsistent is a complaint you can make without having to make a more extensive case about the merits of your complaint.  As such, "it is inconsistent" is going to be a complaint that shows up with a frequency far higher than its weight justifies?

Comment: @RayNicholus Just curious as I cannot come up with anything.  What visual impairment would having the +/- help that color or position do not help?

Comment: @NathanOliver A user with a screen reader that doesn't report color and doesn't reproduce the "this number on top of this number" wouldn't be showing the color or the position.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks.  I forget about those.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: @NathanOliver That said, the tooltip text (on this question anyhow, does say "20 up / 9 down"), so a screenreader actually might do better on this anyhow.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That's probably not true. It doesn't look like any screen readers will observe a title attribute on a <span>. SO is not using this attribute correctly either. http://files.paciellogroup.com/resources/articles/WE05/forms.html

Comment: @raynicholus Well, I guess it's not so good then. I guess if someone is reading the source, they might get something.  I don't think that scores many accessibility points, though.